# combine multiple rows from the same table (days of the week)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

I have a table which stores yes/no values for each hour of the day for a particular user/filter/type.  Each day is its own row.  So there will always be 7 rows for any given user/filter/type combination.

What I am trying to accomplish is one result for each user/filter/type combination that contains all hours of each day of the week.  I think the approach I need here is self joining with aliases and groups, but everything I have tried fails.  I have setup a basic fiddle at [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/082d9f/2)

I also have the ability to change the db schema for this as well if there is an easier and/or preferred method to handle this on the db side (my gut says there is).  Perhaps a table for each day of the week linked by filter_id?

```
INSERT INTO filters
 (`filter_id`, `user_id`, `filter`, `type`, `day`, `12a`, `1a`... and so on for each hour)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'filter1', 1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 'filter1', 1, 2, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 'filter1', 1, 3, 1, 1),
(4, 1, 'filter1', 1, 4, 1, 1),
(5, 1, 'filter1', 1, 5, 1, 1),
(6, 1, 'filter1', 1, 6, 1, 1),
(7, 1, 'filter1', 1, 7, 1, 1),
(8, 1, 'filter2', 1, 1, 0, 0),
(9, 1, 'filter2', 1, 2, 0, 0),
(10, 1, 'filter2', 1, 3, 0, 0),
(11, 1, 'filter2', 1, 4, 0, 0),
(12, 1, 'filter2', 1, 5, 0, 0),
(13, 1, 'filter2', 1, 6, 0, 0),
(14, 1, 'filter2', 1, 7, 0, 0),
(15, 1, 'filter3', 1, 1, 0, 0),
(16, 1, 'filter3', 1, 2, 0, 0),
(17, 1, 'filter3', 1, 3, 0, 0),
(18, 1, 'filter3', 1, 4, 0, 0),
(19, 1, 'filter3', 1, 5, 0, 0),
(20, 1, 'filter3', 1, 6, 0, 0),
(21, 1, 'filter3', 1, 7, 0, 0)
;
```

**EDIT :**

I made some progress on this and it is showing all day hours for the filter in one result...however... I it does not work when a user has more than one filter. I can't seem to get the grouping correct and/or something else so results only show unique user/type/filter combinations... at the moment it only shows one filter result for each user.

This is only joining monday, tuesday, wednesday as well... there must be an easier way to do this.  Like I said I am totally open up to changing the schema of the db for this as well, but not sure what the best approach would be other than this.  I certainly cannot list all the hours for the entire week in one table (that would be 168 columns for hours plus an additional for for 172 in each row).

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT users.user_id, users.username, c.computer_name, filters.user_id, filters.filter, filters.type,
    monday.12a as m12a,
    monday.1a as m1a,
    monday.2a as m2a,
    monday.3a as m3a,
    monday.4a as m4a,
    monday.5a as m5a,
    monday.6a as m6a,
    monday.7a as m7a,
    monday.8a as m8a,
    monday.9a as m9a,
    monday.10a as m10a,
    monday.11a as m11a,
    monday.12p as m12p,
    monday.1p as m1p,
    monday.2p as m2p,
    monday.3p as m3p,
    monday.4p as m4p,
    monday.5p as m5p,
    monday.6p as m6p,
    monday.7p as m8p,
    monday.9p as m9p,
    monday.10p as m10p,
    monday.11p as m11p,
    tuesday.12a as t12a,
    tuesday.1a as t1a,
    tuesday.2a as t2a,
    tuesday.3a as t3a,
    tuesday.4a as t4a,
    tuesday.5a as t5a,
    tuesday.6a as t6a,
    tuesday.7a as t7a,
    tuesday.8a as t8a,
    tuesday.9a as t9a,
    tuesday.10a as t10a,
    tuesday.11a as t11a,
    tuesday.12p as t12p,
    tuesday.1p as t1p,
    tuesday.2p as t2p,
    tuesday.3p as t3p,
    tuesday.4p as t4p,
    tuesday.5p as t5p,
    tuesday.6p as t6p,
    tuesday.7p as t8p,
    tuesday.9p as t9p,
    tuesday.10p as t10p,
    tuesday.11p as t11p,
    wednesday.12a as w12a,
    wednesday.1a as w1a,
    wednesday.2a as w2a,
    wednesday.3a as w3a,
    wednesday.4a as w4a,
    wednesday.5a as w5a,
    wednesday.6a as w6a,
    wednesday.7a as w7a,
    wednesday.8a as w8a,
    wednesday.9a as w9a,
    wednesday.10a as w10a,
    wednesday.11a as w11a,
    wednesday.12p as w12p,
    wednesday.1p as w1p,
    wednesday.2p as w2p,
    wednesday.3p as w3p,
    wednesday.4p as w4p,
    wednesday.5p as w5p,
    wednesday.6p as w6p,
    wednesday.7p as w8p,
    wednesday.9p as w9p,
    wednesday.10p as w10p,
    wednesday.11p as w11p   
    FROM
        ( SELECT account_id, computer_id, computer_name
            FROM computers
            WHERE account_id = 1
            ORDER BY computer_id ASC LIMIT 0, 5
        ) as c
        LEFT JOIN users
            on users.computer_id = c.computer_id

        LEFT JOIN filters
            on filters.user_id = users.user_id

        LEFT JOIN filters as monday
            on monday.user_id = filters.user_id and monday.filter = filters.filter and monday.day = 1

        LEFT JOIN filters as tuesday
            on tuesday.user_id = filters.user_id and tuesday.filter = filters.filter and tuesday.day = 2

        LEFT JOIN filters as wednesday
            on wednesday.user_id = filters.user_id and wednesday.filter = filters.filter and wednesday.day = 3


    WHERE filters.type = 1
    GROUP BY users.user_id
");
```

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: Each unique user/filter/type has 7 rows - one for each day.  I want to combine all those days into the same result.  So for example... 1, filter1, 1, (every hour of each day)... would be one result and so on for each unique user/filter/type in the table.

Comment: Amend your post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Here is the official mysql page. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html